# Create a redirect from the attachments directory to index.php with the slug as a url parameter

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

When a user directly accesses the uploads directory I need to be able to redirect the user to index.php?file=$1. For example:

```
someurl.com/uploads/sites/17/2018/10/image.jpg
```

to

```
someurl.com/index.php?file=/sites/17/2018/10/image.jpg
```

From this url I will be able to check against the current logged in users meta.

Comment: Do you want to prevent direct access to the entire uploads directory or just images (or other files)?

Comment: @Jamie_D I think the rule needs to be like: have we directly visited a file grab the part after the word upload and add it to the query string. Once there I can run a function to check user permissions.

Comment: Updated answer for accessing user info and file parmeters ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281500/protecting-direct-access-to-pdf-and-zip-unless-user-logged-in-without-plugin) :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|zip|jpeg|jpg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ index.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Updated for template redirect function:

```
function check_access_metadata()
{
    $dirCheck = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $requestFile = $dirCheck['basename'];
        if( strpos ( $dirCheck['dirname'] , 'uploads' ) > 0  ){
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                //Do something with registered user
            } else {
                //Do something with guest
            }
        }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_access_metadata' );
```

Comment: Works, but is a little too harsh, is there any way to only use this rule if the file is accessed directly / downloaded and not just used in an image tag?

Comment: I'm still a bit hazy on what you want to accomplish. Can you clarify the best possible outcome? Do you actually want to redirect users, or do you want to run a function when they access an object in the uploads directory?

Comment: If someone directly goes to the attachment url / right click downloads then I want to run a function that checks if the user is logged in.If they are then download away, else 404.However I want the images to display on the website, in an image tag for example, even if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Check [this solution](https://wpguru.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-prevent-direct-file-access-in-your-wp-content-directory/)

Comment: Hmm, this is for hot linking. It doesn't redirect if I view the attachment URL.